# Linux kernel module : my variable lost its value when it's used in thread function

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing a Linux kernel module which read my embedded board button code and use it in order to turn on/off the board led.

When I push button, the module is sending correctly the button code, which is 260, to user-space.

Now, from user-space, I am using the write function in order to re-send this code kernel module :

```
write(fd, buf_wr, strlen(buf_wr));
```

Where **fd** is the file descriptor of my module, and **buf_wr** is the buffer which will be written to the file.

In kernel space, I am using the `write_pid` function in this way :

```
static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    char cod_buf[12];

    printk("WE ARE IN WRITE_PID FUNCTION\n");
    copy_from_user(cod_buf, buffer, length);
    sscanf(cod_buf, "%i", &lcode);
    printk("lcode = %i\n", lcode);

    return 0;
}
```

I defined `lcode` in my kernel module as a global variable :

```
int lcode = 0;
```

and I can see that it is receiving the correct button code which is 260.

Now, I created a thread in the module, I want this thread to run some instructions basing on the button code :

```
int write_in_thread(void *data) {

    printk("Under write_in_thread, lcode = %i\n", lcode);

    switch (lcode) {
        case 260:
        //instructions....
        //instructions....
        //instructions....
        break;

        default :
        //instructions....
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here, I can see that, `Under write_in_thread, lcode = 0`. It's not **260**. So the case statement is running the default one which I don't need here.

How can I fix the `lcode` variable in order to keep it's value in the thread function?

Thank you!

Comment: You should pass it in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: *When* do you create the thread? Is the thread running before or after `write_pid` is called? Please try to create a [mcve] (as much as it's possible) to show us, so we can better see what you're really doing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I created the thread in the initialization of the module, under init function. It's running before `write_pid` is called.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Can you please clarify more for me ? How can I pass it in a thread safe manner ?

Comment: So with the code you show, the thread function will print the still zero value of `lcode`, go through the `switch` and return. Probably long before the `write_pid` function is called and the value of `lcode` is modified.

Comment: @gaston In a multi-threaded environment, passing values from one thread to another shouldn't be done using global variables, but rather through a message queue, etc.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, in the Linux kernel it rather too much churn to do like you are suggesting. The best approach is to have shared pointer to the certain data structure (in which you have a lock member to serialize accesses to its fields).